# A seemingly silly way of using the Stream API that leads to the need for Predicate<Boolean>

Tags: functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

A predicate on booleans seems a little silly to me (well, at least in the following scenario):

```
static Set<A> aSet = ...;

checkCondition(B b) {
    return aSet.stream()
               .map(b::aMethodReturningBoolean)
               .filter((Boolean check) -> check)
               .limit(1).count() > 0;
}
```

What I am doing is that given the object `b`, checking whether there is at least one member of `aSet` that satisfies a certain condition with respect to `b`.

Everything is working fine, but the line `filter((Boolean check) -> check)` is like a tiny little pin pricking me! Is there a way I can avoid it? I mean, if I have a line in my code that is literally the identity function, then there must be something wrong with my approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is

```
return aSet.stream().anyMatch(b::aMethodReturningBoolean);
```

which is much more readable.

Comment: Great! I have so far been using the sequence of steps `filter().limit(1).count() > 0` everywhere in my code. This is so much better. Although, if an item satistying the predicate is found, then `limit(1)` ensures that further computations are not carried out.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right. I missed the limit(1). Edited the answer.

Comment: For parallel stream the `anyMatch` is still much more efficient than OPs version with `limit(1)`. In general `limit`/`skip` operations work badly on parallel streams, thus should be avoided if possible.